# How to update local branch with remote main in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

What is the process of updating my local branch with remote main in IntelliJ?

In the terminal I have done merging like this:

```
$ git checkout main
(main)$ git pull
(main)$ git checkout my-branch
(my-branch)$ git merge main
```

And rebase like this. Stay in the branch and rebase with remote main (no need to update local main):

```
(my-branch)$ git rebase origin/main
```

In IntelliJ the only option I have seen is, while in `main`, go to `my-branch` drop down menu and click on `rebase main onto my-branch`. I assume I would need to first update local main.

Answer (score 0):

Your example commands are correct for the different ways to update your local branch `my-branch` with the latest changes on `main`. Note though you can simplify your merge to work similarly as the rebase, like this:

```
git fetch # update your local copy of origin/main

# choose either merge
git merge origin/main

# or rebase
git rebase origin/main
```

It appears the problem you're having in the UI is that you are trying to rebase while `main` is checked out. Regardless of whether you merge or rebase, you are going to modify the branch you have checked out<sup>1</sup>, so even for rebase you should still have `my-branch` checked out in the UI, and then you can choose the option to either merge in `origin/main` or rebase onto `origin/main`.

Note you should always fetch before rebasing onto (or merging in) `origin/main`. In this way you can save the step of first checking out `main` and then pulling.

---

<sup>1</sup> The rebase command actually takes a second argument which is the commit you wish to start from, and if that commit is a branch name it will check that branch out for you. So even if you had some other branch checked out, you could do this all in one command:

```
git rebase origin/main my-branch
```

and that will first check out `my-branch` and then rebase it onto `origin/main`.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA, you could click the Git Branch widget in IDEA's right bottom status bar (or in the top-left if you are using the new UI), then click the local main branch name, and choose the `Update` button to update it.
It will fetch it from remote and subsequently apply changes to the selected branch.

See the documentation here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sync-with-a-remote-repository.html#update-git-branch

Answer (score 0):

IDEA's UI is not very intuitive here. In the Git view...

1. Make sure `my-branch` is currently checked out
2. Open the `main` branch's context window and select "Update"
3. Open the `main` branch's context window and select "Rebase 'my-branch' onto 'main'"

   - Note: Here, `my-branch` is technically "the currently checked-out branch

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Update doesn't work as expected for me. It fails with rejected (non-fast-forward). Looking at the console, it tried to do a git fetch. Checking out main and doing Update again, it fetches with no error but local doesn't match changes from remote. The terminal seems easier and more reliable than the UI.

Comment: I agree. However, your title calls out IntelliJ and your description mentions a drop down menu so i assumed you wanted a UI way of doing it.